# Nodes import using Feed module node publish by default if there is no status field in XML

Tags: drupal, drupal-feeds

When we import nodes using Feed module imported nodes needs to be published by default even if there is no status field in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Feeds Tamper module we can rewrite before the node being saved.

Steps:

1. Navigate to admin/structure/feeds//tamper
2. Find your Xpathparser(Eg: 
   xpathparser:5 -> Published status Published status)
3. Add plugin - > Set value or default value and set the default value to 1